# Why image preview is duplicated when using alpinejs and livewire in laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

Why image preview is duplicated when using alpinejs and livewire in laravel 9?

Alpinejs already included in Laravel with defer.

The code drag and drop the images and shows their preview before submit. However, when I add **wire:model=photo** it duplicated the image preview, otherwise working perfectly.

Please have a look at below code which is inside livewire component.

```
    <div x-data="dataFileDnD()" class="relative flex flex-col p-4 text-gray-400 border border-gray-200 rounded">
        <form wire:submit.prevent="save" x-ref="dnd"
            class="relative flex flex-col text-gray-400 border border-gray-200 border-dashed rounded cursor-pointer">
            <input accept="images/*" type="file" multiple wire:model="photo"
                class="absolute inset-0 z-50 w-full h-full p-0 m-0 outline-none opacity-0 cursor-pointer"
                x-on:change="addFiles($event)"
                x-on:dragover="$refs.dnd.classList.add('border-blue-400'); $refs.dnd.classList.add('ring-4'); $refs.dnd.classList.add('ring-inset');"
                x-on:dragleave="$refs.dnd.classList.remove('border-blue-400'); $refs.dnd.classList.remove('ring-4'); $refs.dnd.classList.remove('ring-inset');"
                x-on:drop="$refs.dnd.classList.remove('border-blue-400'); $refs.dnd.classList.remove('ring-4'); $refs.dnd.classList.remove('ring-inset');"
                title="" />
            <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-10 text-center">
                <svg class="w-6 h-6 mr-1 text-current-50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                        d="M4 16l4.586-4.586a2 2 0 012.828 0L16 16m-2-2l1.586-1.586a2 2 0 012.828 0L20 14m-6-6h.01M6 20h12a2 2 0 002-2V6a2 2 0 00-2-2H6a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2z" />
                </svg>
                <p class="m-0">Drag your files here or click in this area.</p>
            </div>
        </form>

        <template x-if="files.length > 0">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 mt-4 md:grid-cols-6" x-on:drop.prevent="drop($event)"
                x-on:dragover.prevent="$event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'">
                <template x-for="(_, index) in Array.from({ length: files.length })">
                    <div class="relative flex flex-col items-center overflow-hidden text-center bg-gray-100 border rounded cursor-move select-none"
                        style="padding-top: 100%;" x-on:dragstart="dragstart($event)" x-on:dragend="fileDragging = null"
                        :class="{ 'border-blue-600': fileDragging == index }" draggable="true" :data-index="index">
                        <button class="absolute top-0 right-0 z-50 p-1 bg-white rounded-bl focus:outline-none"
                            type="button" x-on:click="remove(index)">
                            <svg class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-700" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                    d="M19 7l-.867 12.142A2 2 0 0116.138 21H7.862a2 2 0 01-1.995-1.858L5 7m5 4v6m4-6v6m1-10V4a1 1 0 00-1-1h-4a1 1 0 00-1 1v3M4 7h16" />
                            </svg>
                            <span x-text="index"></span>
                        </button>
                        <template x-if="files[index].type.includes('image/')">
                            <img class="absolute inset-0 z-0 object-cover w-full h-full border-4 border-white preview"
                                x-bind:src="loadFile(files[index])" />
                        </template>
                        <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 flex flex-col p-2 text-xs bg-white bg-opacity-50">
                            <span class="w-full font-bold text-gray-900 truncate"
                                x-text="files[index].name">Loading</span>
                            <span class="text-xs text-gray-900" x-text="humanFileSize(files[index].size)">...</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="absolute inset-0 z-40 transition-colors duration-300"
                            x-on:dragenter="dragenter($event)" x-on:dragleave="fileDropping = null"
                            :class="{ 'bg-blue-200 bg-opacity-80': fileDropping == index && fileDragging != index }">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/create-file-list"></script>
        <script>
            function dataFileDnD() {
                return {
                    files: [],
                    fileDragging: null,
                    fileDropping: null,
                    humanFileSize(size) {
                        const i = Math.floor(Math.log(size) / Math.log(1024));
                        return (
                            (size / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(2) * 1 +
                            " " + ["B", "kB", "MB", "GB", "TB"][i]
                        );
                    },
                    remove(index) {
                        let files = [...this.files];
                        files.splice(index, 1);

                        this.files = createFileList(files);
                    },
                    drop(e) {
                        let removed, add;
                        let files = [...this.files];

                        removed = files.splice(this.fileDragging, 1);
                        files.splice(this.fileDropping, 0, ...removed);

                        this.files = createFileList(files);

                        this.fileDropping = null;
                        this.fileDragging = null;
                    },
                    dragenter(e) {
                        let targetElem = e.target.closest("[draggable]");

                        this.fileDropping = targetElem.getAttribute("data-index");
                    },
                    dragstart(e) {
                        this.fileDragging = e.target
                            .closest("[draggable]")
                            .getAttribute("data-index");
                        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
                    },
                    loadFile(file) {
                        const preview = document.querySelectorAll(".preview");
                        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                        preview.forEach(elem => {
                            elem.onload = () => {
                                URL.revokeObjectURL(elem.src); // free memory
                            };
                        });

                        return blobUrl;
                    },
                    addFiles(e) {
                        const files = createFileList([...this.files], [...e.target.files]);
                        this.files = files;
                    }
                };
            }
        </script>
</div>
```